# How to find out max or latest date? How to create Calculate fields? How to delete a field? - Rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

Below are the questions i have asked on github.com/rethinkdb issues which they have answered.
I am posting here for the benefit of rethinkdb community

**1.How to filter max date from the below data:**

```
[   
{"TimeStamp": Fri Oct 11 2013 05:51:12 GMT+00:00},
{"TimeStamp": Thu Oct 10 2013 15:41:09 GMT+00:00},
{"TimeStamp": Thu Oct 10 2013 15:44:04 GMT+00:00}
]
```

**2.How to create Calculated fields?I have data like this in rethinkdb**

```
[
{id: 1, sales: 1000, discount: 0.1},
{id: 2, sales: 2000, discount: 0.2},
{id: 3, sales:3000, discount: 0.1}
]
```

How can i transform that as below:

```
[{id: 1, sales: 1000, discount: 0.1, discAmt: 100, netSales: 900},
{id: 2, sales: 2000, discount: 0.2, discAmt: 400, netSales: 1600},
{id: 3, sales: 3000, discount: 0.1, discAmt: 300, netSales: 2700}
]
```

**How to delete discount field from the above?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. Max Date**

For the max timestamp, if you just want to retrieve the last timestamp, you can do

```
r.table("foo").map( r.row("TimeStamp") ).reduce( function(left, right) {
   return r.branch( left.gt(right),
    left,
    right
})
```

If you want the document with the greatest timestamp, you can do

```
r.table("foo").orderBy(r.desc("TimeStamp")).limit(1)
```

This will sort the whole table, so you may want to create an index on TimeStamp and use

```
r.table("foo").orderBy({index: "TimeStamp"}).limit(1)
```

**2.Calculated fields**

```
r.db("books").table("sales").update( function(row){ 
  var discAmt = row("sales").mul(row("discount")); 
    return {
    discAmt: discAmt,
    netSales: row("sales").sub(discAmt)
 }
})
.run()
```

**3.Deleting a field**

```
 r.db("books").table("sales").replace( function(row) {
     return row.unpick("discount");
 })
 .run()
```

I hope this will help the rethinkdb starter's like me.

Thanks